# how to make first row as header in text file using awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

input as a csv file is shown below

```
name,id no,marks in cc  
xyzc,10000,56   
ABCb,10001,75   
xyza,10000,56  
xyz1,10000,56
```

Expected output is as follows i.e. a text file were separator is also replaced from ',' to '^' and after line 1 dotted line is added.

```
name ^ id no ^ marks in cc  
...........................
xyzc ^ 10000 ^ 56   
ABCb ^ 10001 ^ 75   
xyza ^ 10000 ^ 56  
xyz1 ^ 10000 ^ 56
```

how can I do such arrangements in awk can anyone please help to resolve this

Comment: Do you want `^` in place of `,` only? Please confirm once.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt so far? Hard to help debug your code without seeing your code. It's great that you've included sample input and expected output, but try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/ ^ /g;1p;1s/././g' file
```

Replace all `,`'s by `^`'s. Print the first line and then replace the first line by `.`'s.

Answer (score 2):

A slight alternative, but essentially the same

```
awk '{gsub(/,/," ^ ")}1;(NR==1){gsub(/./,".")}(NR==1)'  file
```

This code essentially does the following:

1. read a line and store it in `$0` (this is the default, there is not code written for this)
2. **`{gsub(/,/," ^ ")}`:** substitute all `,` <comma>'s with the string `" ^ "` <space><hat><space> and store everything in `$0`
3. **`1`:** this is a shorthand which is equivalent to `{print $0}`, so print the string `$0`
4. **`(NR==1){action}`:** If the record/line number `NR` is equal to 1, perform `action` where `action` is

   1. **`{gsub(/./,".")}`:** substitute all characters by a `.` <dot>. This creates your underline
5. **`(NR==1)`:** this is equivalent to `(NR==1)1` which is equivalent to `(NR==1){print $0}` which states if the record/line number is equal to one, print `$0` again which is now a string of dots.
6. Go back to **1**

**note:** points **4** and **5** could have been merged as `(NR==1){gsub(/./,".");print $0}`

Another solution is:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1;(NR==1){gsub(/./,".")}(NR==1)'  FS=, OFS=" ^ " file
```

This code essentially does the following:

1. **`FS=, OFS=" ^ "`:** Set the field separator to `,` <comma> and the output field separator to the string `" ^ "` <space><hat><space>
2. read a line and store it in `$0` (this is the default, there is not code written for this)
3. **`{$1=$1}`:** rebuild `$0` by replacing all `FS` with `OFS`. This essentially equivalent to `awk '{gsub(/,/," ^ ")}` in the first case.
4. **`1`:** this is a shorthand which is equivalent to `{print $0}`, so print the string `$0`
5. **`(NR==1){action}`:** If the record/line number `NR` is equal to 1, perform `action` where `action` is

   1. **`{gsub(/./,".")}`:** substitute all characters by a `.` <dot>. This creates your underline
6. **`(NR==1)`:** this is equivalent to `(NR==1)1` which is equivalent to `(NR==1){print $0}` which states if the record/line number is equal to one, print `$0` again which is now a string of dots.
7. Go back to **2**

This can even be shortened as

```
awk '($1=$1);(NR==1) && gsub(/./,".")'  FS=, OFS=" ^ " file
```

but this becomes more cryptic and not readable and even introduces a tiny possibility for a bug (see the comment of Ed Morton below this post)

Never aim for the shortest version but the most readable and easiest to debug.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the first one..just to have me some knowledge : )

Comment: When you use actions as conditions without a specific need in mind you obfuscate your code and often introduce input-dependent bugs (as you did in this case - try `echo '0' | awk '$1=$1'`). So just don't do that - unless you have a specific **need** to do otherwise, always put actions in an action block even if it costs you an extra character once in a while.

Comment: @User123 I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, another contest. :-/

I like potong's sed solution the best so far.  But here's a super small awk solution:

```
awk -F, '$1=$1;NR==1&&gsub(/./,".")' OFS=" ^ " file.csv
```

Here's what we're doing:

- `-F,` - sets the input field separator to `,`.
- `$1=$1` - sets the first field to the first field. This (1) rewrites the line to replace `FS` with `OFS` and (2) should always evaluate to `true` thereby printing the line. This causes every line to be printed, with the input field separators replaced with output field separators.
- `NR==1&&gsub(...)` - this prints the dotted line by substituting all other characters with a dot, if we're still on the first line.
- `OFS=" ^ "` - sets the output field separator.

The way this awk solution differs from other answers is that it embeds functionality like creating the dotted line within conditions that are used to determine whether to print the line.

Normally, awk scripts are considered to consist of `condition { statement }` pairs, but you'll note that there are no curly brackets in this awk script. A missing `{ statement }` is considered to be a `{print}`. So the script consists of two pairs with missing statements -- the first one is evaluated for every line, and the second is evaluated only for the first line, and is used to created the dotted line.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    gsub(",", " ^ ");
    print;
    if (NR == 1) {
        gsub(/./, ".");
        print;
    }
}
```

The key idea is that `NR` is the number of records processed by awk
so far.  You can test this variable to manage special handling for the
first line (or for any specific line).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=' ^ ' '{$1=$1; print} NR==1{gsub(/./,"."); print}' file
name ^ id no ^ marks in cc
..........................
xyzc ^ 10000 ^ 56
ABCb ^ 10001 ^ 75
xyza ^ 10000 ^ 56
xyz1 ^ 10000 ^ 56
```

In general when you don't already have a string to convert to some repetition of chars, to print a string of chars (or strings!) of some specific length `N` you use `str=sprintf("%*s",N,"")` and then replace every blank char in the output with the char (or string) `C` you want printed using `gsub(/ /,"C",str)`.

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=' ^ ' '{$1=$1; print} NR==1{dots=sprintf("%*s",length($0),""); gsub(/ /,".",dots); print dots}' file
name ^ id no ^ marks in cc
..........................
xyzc ^ 10000 ^ 56
ABCb ^ 10001 ^ 75
xyza ^ 10000 ^ 56
xyz1 ^ 10000 ^ 56
```